# Form validation using React, EmailJS and Bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, forms, validation, react-bootstrap

So I'm trying to get my form validation to work using EmailJs and Bootstrap within React for a simple contact form. I got the validation to work on the UI, however, it will still  send the email even if the fields are red and required. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? I followed the examples here: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/forms/validation/ and here: https://www.emailjs.com/docs/examples/reactjs/ but it does not seem to be working correctly.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

**EDIT**
I was able to solve this by using a handleSubmit function after my sendEmail function. Please see updated code below.

I also added a way to clear the form by setting setValidated(false); e.target.reset(); within .then() method after the user submits the form...Hopefully this will help others struggling with this.

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";
import emailjs from "@emailjs/browser";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
import PageTitle from "../components/PageTitle";
import Form from "react-bootstrap/Form";
import Row from "react-bootstrap/Row";
import Col from "react-bootstrap/Col";
import FloatingLabel from "react-bootstrap/FloatingLabel";

import config from "../configData.json";

import "./Contact.scss";

export const Contact = () => {
  const [validated, setValidated] = useState(false);
  const form = useRef();

  const sendEmail = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    emailjs
      .sendForm(
        config.serviceId,
        config.templateId,
        "#contact-form",
        config.publicKey
      )
      .then(
        () => {
          alert("Your message has been sent.");
          setValidated(false);
          e.target.reset();
        },
        (error) => {
          alert("There was a problem sending your message.", error);
        }
      );
  };

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    const form = event.currentTarget;
    if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
    } else {
      // alert("Message was sent!");
      sendEmail(event);
    }
    setValidated(true);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <PageTitle title="Contact" />
      <div className="container my-5">
        <h2 className="mb-4">Leave a Message</h2>
        <Form
          noValidate
          ref={form}
          onSubmit={handleSubmit}
          validated={validated}
          id="contact-form"
        >
          <Row>
            <Form.Group as={Col} md="12" controlId="nameValidation">
              <FloatingLabel
                controlId="floatingInput"
                label="Name"
                className="mb-3"
              >
                <Form.Control
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Name"
                  name="user_name"
                  size="lg"
                  required
                />
                <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
                  Please enter your name.
                </Form.Control.Feedback>
                <Form.Control.Feedback>Looks good!</Form.Control.Feedback>
              </FloatingLabel>
            </Form.Group>
            <Form.Group as={Col} md="12" controlId="emailValidation">
              <FloatingLabel
                controlId="floatingInput"
                label="Email"
                className="mb-3"
              >
                <Form.Control
                  type="email"
                  placeholder="name@example.com"
                  name="user_email"
                  size="lg"
                  required
                />
                <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
                  Please enter a valid email.
                </Form.Control.Feedback>
                <Form.Control.Feedback>Looks good!</Form.Control.Feedback>
              </FloatingLabel>
            </Form.Group>
            <Form.Group as={Col} md="12" controlId="messageValidation">
              <FloatingLabel
                controlId="floatingInput"
                label="Message"
                className="mb-3"
              >
                <Form.Control
                  placeholder="Message"
                  name="user_message"
                  size="lg"
                  required
                  as="textarea"
                  rows={3}
                />
                <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
                  Please enter a message.
                </Form.Control.Feedback>
                <Form.Control.Feedback>Looks good!</Form.Control.Feedback>
              </FloatingLabel>
            </Form.Group>
          </Row>
          <Button
            type="submit"
            value="Send"
            variant="primary"
            size="lg"
            className="mt-3 w-100"
          >
            SEND
          </Button>
        </Form>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Contact;
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please share your HTML where you are getting this info?
Even required, you can make the `type='email' required` so it will validade for you.

if that still a problem (which should not be), then make an `IF` to validade for you.

Here is an example. You can use the function below to validade if it is an email. Send the email typed by the user via parameter.

```js
     const validateEmail = (email) => {
       return String(email)
       .toLowerCase()
       .match(
      /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/
        );
     };
```

Comment: Hi, so the email is already set to required. Note this is using react and the HTML is within the return method. Curious to how you would write the IF statement function to validate. Can you show an example via code? Thanks

Comment: Just edited my comment above with an example

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. It turns out I just needed to write a function to handle submit after the sendEmail function. I have updated my code above for any others who may be struggling with this.

Comment: Don't forget to close this question by clicking in the checkmark on the left of my comment